# C++ override operator= to call ToInt() method

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

Hi i'm trying to overload the assignment operator of a class to return an class Member (data).

```
class A{
 public:
  int32_t ToInt32() { return this->data; }
  void SetData(int32_t data) { this->data=data; }
 private:
  int32_t data;
}
```

I want to overload the = operator, so that i can do the following:

```
A *a = new A();
a->SetData(10);
int32_t Testint;
Testint = a;
```

and now `a` should be `10`.

How can i do that?

Comment: You can't overload the `operator=()` for primitive types. What you can do is provide a cast operator for `A`, but the assignment should look like this then: `Testint = *a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t do that since `a` is a pointer. You can only overload operators for custom types (and pointers are *not* custom types).

But using a pointer here is nonsense anyway. You can make the following work:

```
A a = A{};
a.SetData(10);
int32_t Testint;
Testint = a;
```

In order to do this, you overload the implicit-conversion-to-`int32_t` operator, not `operator=`:

```
public:
    operator int32_t() const { return data; }
```

A word on code style: having setters is usually a very bad idea – initialise your class in the constructor. And don’t declare variables without initialising them. So your code should actually look like this:

```
A a = A{10};
int32_t Testint = a;
```

… two lines instead of four. The definition of `A` becomes simpler as well:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int32_t data) : data{data} {}

    operator int32_t() const { return data; }

private:
    int32_t data;
};
```

Comment: This works fine - but i need a to be a Pointer because in my program i have an Array of Pointers to Objects. I take on Element (a Pointer) of the Array and can use a ToInt function of the class. Isn`t there a posibility to do this with operator overloading?

Comment: @Haselnussstrauch like I said that's not possible. Furthermore, **you almost certainly do not need to use pointers** in the array, and you shouldn't use them. Pointers are extremely overused in C++.

Comment: @Haselnussstrauch of course it does but (a) the operator still doesn't work on a pointer, you are dereferencing it; and (b) really, don't use pointers here. There are several discussions on Stack Overflow explaining in great detail why this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide conversion operator:

```
class A{
...
    operator int32_t() const 
    { 
       return this->data;
    }
};
```

Any conversion operator is implemented as:

```
operator DATATYPE()
{
    return ...;
}
```

The return type of such conversion operator is `DATATYPE` itself (hence `int32_t` in code given above). 
Since this conversion operator doesn't (shouldn't) change the content of this instance, it should be declared `const`.